# How to get all expired keys in redis

Tags: python, database, redis

---

> I have multiple keys in redis with timeout 3min. I need to fetch all
>   the keys which has expired in redis cache.

---

Comment: If you need that keys after the expiration time, then you might want to rethink your expiration policy.

Comment: @KlausD. I need it because I have to fetch all keys later in my mongodb.

Comment: @shaikmoeed I need all keys which has expired. This example is showing how to set timeout.

Comment: Maybe you need to write your own expiration logic?

Comment: Please explain in your own words, what "expired" means.

Comment: @KlausD. If we set timeout of any key 3min. It will deleted from redis after 3min. I need to store that keys before expired.